# Meaning of the swap part in the top command

Tags: linux, top

Do you know in which unit the swap column is display in the top output?

According with top documentation it is in KB, but please take a look in the below image.

[image]

What means g or m next to the swap value?

Thanks in advance for your kind support

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text.  Just paste the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the values in the `SWAP` column, then `g` means "Gibibytes" (GiB) and `m` means "Mebibytes" (MiB).  This is also true for the values in the header (but the letters used are upper-case).

I believe that it is the base 2-based units rather than the base 10-based units that are in use (judging from the `top` manual on a Linux system).

---

According to [this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/474259):

> Top (at least in some versions) calculates SWAP per process as VIRT - RSS instead of reporting real swap usage. Under Linux the result is a completely meaningless number.

And from [another answer at ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/371400):

> The top tool uses a broken formula to calculate what it erroneously reports as swap space. It is in fact the result of subtracting the resident set size from the address space size. This is a boneheaded thing to do since one is a measure of virtual memory and the other is a measure of physical memory. So it's not entirely clear what the result is even a measure of at all.

Comment: I referred to the highlighted column, Swap column. In total I have 21GB swap memory, and the first process is using 57g.

Could this mean 57GB of swap used?

Comment: @federico Ah, I missed that one. It's the same there.

Comment: @federico See updated answer.